# How to clean sealant stuck in pump head?

Tags: maintenance, pump, sealant

I have a old trusty pump that over the years has the presta head filled with tubeles goo. Noways it pumps the tires *very* slow. Is there any chemical way to remove it without melting the plastic?

Comment: What kind of pump?  If its a floor pump with a hose, you can often replace the whole head and hose as an upgrade.

Comment: @Criggie yes, floor pump with a hose. I'll consider replacing the head too, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to disassemble the pump head and clean out the blockage manually.

I’d try 70% isopropyl alcohol as a solvent to help remove sealant.

Comment: Thank you, some medical spirits + smal hex key did the job. Hopefully it's work better now, otherwise I'll change whole head/hose as @Criggie adviced